# Pipenv: Error while trying to remove Virtual Environment

Tags: python, pipenv

I had an error while trying to remove a virtual environment using `pipenv --rm`

```
Running...Error:  An error occurred while removing /home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/daniel-tzppZObm!
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
```

I am the administrator of the PC, I think this should not happen.

Comment: which os do you use? In windows you can't remove dir which is current for any process regardless your rights

Comment: I am using Ubuntu VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"